# i want to install tensor flow in anaconda but it shows error :

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

i tried many ways to install tensor flow on my windows system with anaconda 5.0 and python 3.6

pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install tensorflow

but it shows error[package missing in current channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kwjv.jpg)

after it i also tried to degrade my python version from anaconda navigator after the whole process python version is same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , Solved my problem by reinstalling the anaconda and python 3.5. and after the re-installation i install tensor-flow by anaconda navigator and it worked for me.